# CustomCell without customCell class with storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, storyboard

I would to create a custom cell without create a custom cell class. I know that this is possible. I've created in storyboard a tableviewcontroller with a prototype cell with a label. In the attibutes I've set the cell name "mycell". And the code that I used is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"mycell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) 
   { cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];}
   UILabel *title = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:1];
   title.text = @"Hi";
   return cell;
}
```

But when my app run I see only a empty table without a cell with my label. 
In the tableView methods I've used:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView { return 1;}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section { 
return 5; }
```

Thank you.

Comment: do you see 5 sections?

Comment: I copied your code, and it worked fine for me. Did you set your controller to be the data source for the table view? Did you change the class of the table view controller in IB to be this class (where your posted code is)?

Comment: I set correctly the data source and the delegate and I change the class of the table view controller in storyboard to be this class. But this code still don't work for me.

Comment: Well, there's nothing wrong with the code you posted, so something is wrong in your setup in IB. Did you set the tag?

Comment: I think the same thing. Yes I've insert a label in the custom cell and I've set in the attributes the tag 1 for this label.

Comment: Is the table's content set to "Dynamic Prototypes"?

Comment: You should put a log in cellForRowAtIndexPath to make sure it's even being called. You could put a log in the other two data source methods as well to see if they're called.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding UILabel programmatically it needs to be alloc init, should be given a frame and added to the cell as sub view.

```
UILabel *title = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:1];
title.text = @"Hi";
return cell;
```

Should be

```
UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 10, 50, 20)];
title.text = @"Hi";
[cell addSubview:title];
return cell;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but if I use this code I alloc a Label in the code and there is not corrispondence between the label allocate with label in storyboard with tag 1. I have create a label with tag 1 in storyboard inside the cell and I want use it.

Comment: @user2136333: You mean you already have an outlet for UILabel in XIB with tag 1?

Comment: @Deepesh, the OP doesn't need an outlet since he's referencing the label by its tag that he set in IB.

Comment: With a custom cell in storyboard i don't need of an outlet and I know that is sufficient the code: UILabel *title = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:1]; but the label don't appear

Comment: @user2136333: Try adding identifier "mycell" in TableViewCell identifier property, reset app in simulator and then try. I was having same issue and tried above mentioned step and label started showing text.